# What is the amount of extra interest I have to pay along with my tax due?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, india, penalty

My total tax payable is 60803 for the financial year 2012-2013. But, TDS deducted till 31st 2013 is 50822, so I have to pay the tax due of 9981. What is the exact amount I have to pay? Is there interest or penalty added to the 9981, or will I only have to pay the amount due (9981)? Is there a formula for this penalty calculation?

Comment: Added location tag for you, correct it if its wrong

Answer (score 4):

As a general rule, if the tax obligation due is less than Rs 10,000/- there is no Penalty or Interest to be paid. You can pay the balance [online or via bank] till 31-July as "Self Assesment tax"

You have not given the full details as to how much was the income, was this in form of salary or other income. The Tax paid as this TDS or Advance Tax. All these matter when determining the penalty.

Refer to this document for more details.  http://incometaxindia.gov.in/Archive/Taxation_Of_Salaried_Employees_18062012.pdf

The Income Tax depeatment has also provided XLS Utility where you need to fill in your numbers and it will calcuate the tax [including any penalty] that needs to be paid. This is available at https://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/ in the bottom left hand under downloads.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, there is a 12% per annum interest rate (subject to change) applied on the overdue tax amount, calculated on a daily compounding basis.