# Form 16 for 0 tax payee?

Tags: income-tax, india, tax-deduction, payroll-taxes, tax-exemption

I have several questions regarding tax computation,

1. Do we have 2 form 16 for a financial year?
2. If his salary is below tax bar, will he get the form 16?
3. If tax is paid for 3 quarter of a financial year, last quarter tax is not paid. How to calculate the tax amount for this quarter. How to pay the tax and how to file that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> Do we have 2 form 16 for a financial year?

The Form 16 is issued by the employer showing the salary paid and the taxes deducted and deposited on your behalf with the Income Tax. The number of form 16 will be equal to the number to employments you have had in a financial year

> If his salary is below tax bar, will he get the form 16?

Yes. The form 16 is issued by employer, if a person is in employment. If there is no tax liability, the form 16 will show zero tax deducted.

> If tax is paid for 3 quarter of a financial year, last quarter tax is not paid.

Calculate the total salary, tax on total salary, deduct the tax already paid/deducted. Pay the Balance. Refer to this question for more details [What is the amount of extra interest I have to pay along with my tax due?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/23356/what-is-the-amount-of-extra-interest-i-have-to-pay-along-with-my-tax-due/23357#23357)